# Mysterious bug in javascript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is the code for one of my javascript classes:

```
function Foo(text)
{
   var container = document.createElement('span');
   container.innerHTML = text;
   $("#fooContainer").append(container);

   this.select = function()
   {
       $(container).addClass('selected');
   }

   this.getContainer = function()
   {
       return container;
   }

   this.getText = function()
   {
      return text;
   }
}
```

At each page load I do the following:

```
var fooList = {};

fooList['foo1'] = new Foo('Foo 1');
fooList['foo2'] = new Foo('Foo 2');
fooList['foo3'] = new Foo('Foo 3');
```

This results in the spans for each `foo` object being created correctly, resulting in this in the dom:

```
<div id="fooContainer">
    <span>Foo 1</span>
    <span>Foo 2</span>
    <span>Foo 3</span>
</div>
```

However, if I do this:

```
fooList['foo1'].select();
```

Then it results in this:

```
<div id="fooContainer">
    <span>Foo 1</span>
    <span>Foo 2</span>
    <span class="selected">Foo 3</span>
</div>
```

Rather than what's expected, which is this:

```
<div id="fooContainer">
    <span class="selected">Foo 1</span>
    <span>Foo 2</span>
    <span>Foo 3</span>
</div>
```

It seems like the `container` object of all `foo` objects points to the container of the last foo, which in this case is foo 3. To test it out further I did this:

```
    for (var key in fooList)
    {
        console.log(key);
        console.log( fooList[key].getText() );
        console.log(fooList[key].getContainer() );
    }
```

This results in this being logged in firebug console (only showing it for the first foo):

```
foo1
Foo 1
<span>
```

When I click span, then in firebug, it points to the 3rd of the spans rather than the first or 2nd as expected.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to set an id to the spans?

Comment: Is this really about `document.createElement`? It seems to be doing its job correctly (creating elements).

Comment: I bet on a new/this mess. I'll have a deeper look if nobody coins it.

Comment: I type your code to jsfiddle, and your code works well in there http://jsfiddle.net/AVaEH/1/ .

Comment: "container" is taken from constructor scope in select and always matches container of last created object for all other objects.

Comment: Right, thanks. In my actual code I was missing the `var container` declaration in the body of the `foo` class. Adding that in there, it now works.

Comment: Are you shure that in your code you have `var` before container?

Comment: @jcubic you got it, post it as an answer and i'll accept :)

Comment: haha, @jcubic got the bug. Always use jslint or jshint to avoid those typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you shure that in your code you have `var` before container?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing and matching straight javascript DOM manipulation and jQuery methods.  Don't do that.

If you want to use jQuery to append an element to another, use jQuery to do both, or neither.  So instead of

```
var container = document.createElement('span');
```

use jQuery's version:

```
var container = $("<span>");
```

and of course use JQuery's way of adding html to it:

```
container.html(text);
```

And so on.

If you really muse use `document.createElement()`, I THINK you can get away with:

```
$("#fooContainer").append($(container));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function Foo(text)
{
   var container = document.createElement('span');
   container.innerHTML = text;
   $("#fooContainer").append(container);

   this.container = container
   this.text = text

   this.select = function()
   {
       $(this.container).addClass('selected');
   }

   this.getContainer = function()
   {
       return this.container;
   }

   this.getText = function()
   {
      return this.text;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just right on your proposed solution.
I don't usually write on Jquery, but for what I understand of it, the $() method is used to reference an object by id, or an array of objects by class. Don't know what would happen by passing it a DOM object reference, but internally some browsers re-reference child objects when attaching new DOM elements to the child. Try this:

```
var foo_count = -1;
function Foo(text)
{
   foo_count++;
   var id = foo_count;

   var container = document.createElement('span');
   container.setAttribute('id', "foo_" + id);
   container.innerHTML = text;
   $("#fooContainer").append(container);

   this.select = function()
   {
       $("#foo_" + id).addClass('selected');
   }

   this.getContainer = function()
   {
       return $('#foo_' + id);
   }

   this.getText = function()
   {
      return text;
   }
}
```